# Is there a captive portal / setup portal to setup WiFi on the Raspi? Like on some WiFi range extenders

Tags: wifi, access-point, captive-portal

I am developing a project and for testing, I want to send some raspis to friends but I don't want to know all their WiFi credentials in advance. Is there something so the Raspi will act as an access point at the first start where you can connect and then it shows a page with all the WiFi networks and you can pick one and provide the password and then the pi reboots and connects to this network? Many of the WiFi range extenders I used have this kind of setup.

Comment: Why not use the standard GUI access in RasPi OS?

Comment: I don't want to make them connect a monitor and keyboard.

Comment: I suggest you update your question with relevant information, constraints, etc. BTW: PiOS does not function as an AP out of the box. You may want to have a look at ways to add a wpasupplicant file to the boot partition (assuming you're indeed using PiOS)

Comment: The Pi is no different to any other computer. If you want to use WiFi you need to enter the details.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking if an installation is available with the characteristics you described. The answer is No.

You have to setup an access point. There are many tutorials available how to do it. The other things you want, have to be created by yourself, I think. Maybe you will find some hints on the web, but I don't believe that you will find a ready to install program.

Comment: A "guided" installation would be useful for many... and might eliminate some of the pointless "I want a fixed IP address" questions  :)